# ASP.Net Core in default web site and WCF services in an application in IIS

Tags: wcf, iis, asp.net-core

We have Windows Server 2012 IIS that runs several Applications such as:

```
Default Website <= Need to install ASP.Net Core here
    -   App1        <= running a wcf application in .Net 4
    -   Exchange    Apps    <= running exchange server 2013
    -   App2        <= running an ASP.Net aspx application
```

When I install ASP.Net in Default Web Site, it will run without problems.

Unfortunately, all other IIS applications will stop working with 502 Bad Gateway.
The only solution I did is to redirect request from Default website to a new application under Default Web Site and it works without problems.

I wish I could run our ASP.Net Core application in the IIS\Default Web Site while keeping other IIS applications running in subfolders.

How to achieve this without redirect or using different ports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is ASP.Net Core application adds handler AspNetCoreModule (default name is aspNetCore) to the web.config, which is unmanaged and incompatible with managed code. And your ASP.Net applications just inherit this module and try to execute it, failing at application start.

All you need to do is add the following line to all your child managed ASP.Net applications web.config files (APP1, Exchange, etc):

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <remove name="aspNetCore"/>
            <!--Your other handlers -->
       </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I can not implement your solution because I went to a semi-production environment with my solution of redirecting the home of the ASP.Net application to a subdomain in IIS and it works fine tell the moment. But your solution seems practical and there for I signed it as answered with my many thanks to your interest.

Answer (score 0):

All new or old websites to deploy in IIS can have the port changed:

**Web site does not exist:**

1. Open your IIS
2. Right-click on the Sites folder
3. Select the "Add Web Site" submenu
4. Under the port option, change to an unused port number
5. Make sure that port number is unused

**Web site exists:**

1. Select your created web site
2. On the right side, click on Bindings
3. Select your website in the list box
4. Click on the Edit button
5. Change to the port you want

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I wrote that I want to achieve this without changing ports. I think there is interference between MapRoute in ASP.Net MVC and the other websites. Therefore, I which I could tell ASP.Net Core runtime or IIS to add exceptions for URLs that handles to do no go through ASP.Net Core for backward compatibility. I may add it in some where in web.config or anywhere else. So it will bypass requests from localhost\app1 for example. Is it possible?

Comment: Clear cache,cookies first of your browser then restart it.

Comment: I cleared them but still getting 502 Bad Gateway. What I understand is that ASP.Net Core will catch all requests to the webroot and all its applications not related to it as well. I want to eliminate this behavior.

Comment: check your project framework and the framework installed on server.. check also the framework used by your project in IIS application pool

Comment: is other app running with different port with app1?

Comment: what do you mean by app? Is it means different project? or Its just a page with only on project and a various page?

Comment: It is IIS Application using .Net 4 runtime and hosts wcf services. Another IIS applications are for Exchange Server.

Comment: Can you create a website to separate app1? with different port? I need you try this if its gonna work or not.. For me i am not deploying a website without its own port because it could lead you to vulnerabilities. Using same port with various website its not a good idea. Hope you do this to help you and simulate your problem. Good luck

Comment: Just remove your app1 from Default website and bring it to your newly created website. Remember, don't forget to check the framework of your application pool for your new website created make sure your app1 is running with same framework. If app1 running in framework 4 same with in application pool.